# PHP progress tracking does not work properly with foreach loop unless sleep() is used

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a small php function that I use to track php execution progress. The progress is put into a txt file and retrieved with js function around every 0.1 second.

Now the issue is that the progress bar will only update if I use `sleep(1);` inside the loop although the `refreshProgress()` function runs for about 40 times during the execution of the php script, which is more than enough to data saved in the txt file on around 12 loops.

Also by echoing the file content after it's saved I can see that the percentage is being saved correctly, so I'm not sure where the issue is, I definitly don't want to use sleep function as I'll be running the script on huge amount data later.

here are 2 images to demonstrate the difference when using sleep(1) and when not
[image: using sleep(1)]
[image: Not using sleep()]
Here is the PHP script:

```
$cars = array
      (
      array("Volvo",22,18),
      array("BMW",15,13),
      array("Saab",5,2),
      array("Land Rover",17,15)
      );

$cars_all_count = 13;
$file = "to/this/path/progress.txt";
$i = 0; 

foreach ($cars as $key=>$carslist){
// some function
    foreach($carslist as $single_car){

    $start = microtime(true);
    $i++;

    // usleep(250000);

    UpdateProgress( $file, $i, $cars_all_count );

    $time_elapsed_secs = microtime(true) - $start;
    echo '<pre>loop:'.$i.'<br>';
    print_r($time_elapsed_secs);
    echo '<pre>';

    }
}

function UpdateProgress( $file, $i, $cars_all_count ) {
    // Calculate the percentatage.
    $percent = intval($i/$cars_all_count * 100);
    // Put the progress percentage and message to array.
    $arr_content = $percent;
    // Write the progress into a file
    file_put_contents($file, $arr_content);
    echo file_get_contents($file).'<br>';
}
```

the js function I use to to refresh progress:

```
function refreshProgress() {
    var progress_url = progress_file_link;

    jQuery.get(progress_url, function(response) {
         console.log(response);
        if (response.length == 0){
            return false;
        }
        var parsedData = response;
        jQuery("#progress").find('.bar').css('width', parsedData + '%');

        // console.log(parsedData);
        // If the process is completed, we should stop the checking process.
        if (parsedData == 100) {
            window.clearInterval(timer);
            completed();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What is the difference in the `console.log(response);` when you do and when you don't use the `sleep`?

Comment: "retrieved with js function around every 0.1 second".  Are you saying you are executing the get request every 100 milliseconds?  That's pretty overkill considering the chances of your request not finishing in that time frame is large.

Comment: @Goose without `sleep()` it just returns empty, with  `sleep()`  it returns the correct percentage

Comment: Sounds like there's an error and you have error reporting off. Turn on error reporting and check for errors. Those error messages will make this much easier to figure out.

Comment: @Taplar Exactly, I'll increase it, just trying to find why this is happening, basically eliminating the chance that get function is being delayed.

Comment: @Goose It's enabled, I confirmed and there no error at all.

Comment: I'd be surprised if errors aren't being suppressed. If the code hits the sleep line either way, the echo and print_r are at the same level and would only not run if the code errored before then. Please update you're question to include the code or system configuration you use to enable error reporting.

Comment: @goose Echo and print are all running correctly and outputting the correct data, the issue is that I don't see the same result when retrieved from get function. I think probably because it's running too fast but it's weird again since get function is running more than 40 times for 12 loops

Comment: So basically if each loop lasts a little bit long, the progress is conveyed correctly with no issue. Without using sleep, the output of single iteration is 0.00099992752075195

Comment: You said initially "without sleep() it just returns empty". What I'd like to know is *exactly* what the value inside of `console.log(response);` is with sleep compared to without.

Comment: response will only show the content of the progress.txt file, without sleep it will retun empty string in console.log 40 times, but with sleep it will show the correct progress 12, 28..;and go on. for echo details I just display it inside the page with other ajax function on success, and it show the correct details without an issue. I added images to the question for better demonstration